# Installing Image_Graph and using with BASE

Tags: radix

I have Windows 7 with the latest XAMPP installation. I configured BASE to work, for the most part. My problem is that in BASE, when I click on the graph alerts button, I get this error:

`Error loading the Graphing library:`

Check your Pear::Image_Graph installation!

```
* Image_Graph can be found here:at http://pear.veggerby.dk/. Without this library no graphing operations can be performed.
* Make sure PEAR libraries can be found by php at all:

  pear config-show | grep "PEAR directory"
  PEAR directory      php_dir     /usr/share/pear

  This path must be part of the include path of php (cf. /etc/php.ini):

  php -i | grep "include_path"
  include_path => .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php => .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php</code>
```

I think it may have to do with the include path of the php.ini so here is what it currently says:

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
; http://php.net/include-path
include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"

I am really at a loss as to how to resolve this. I searched for a while for some documentation but most referred to installing on ubuntu.

I don't know any pear or php, so if you know how to fix this please explain thoroughly. I am willing to supply as much information as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading this?
[pear.php.net](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.introduction.php)

I solved my problem on Debian with that.